# AWS alb-ingress-controller failed to create ALB in EKS fargate

Tags: kubernetes, aws-fargate, amazon-eks

Hello Kubernetes experts!
I was trying to follow the documentation below to create an alb-ingress-controller with ingress resources- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/using-alb-ingress-controller-with-amazon-eks-on-fargate/

It's supposed to create an alb and bind the address field of Kubernetes ingress but the address field of ingress is empty! No error.

I documented the steps in my blog at https://blogs.aspnet4you.com/2020/03/17/run-serverless-kubernetes-pods-using-amazon-eks-and-aws-fargate/ and you can see address of ingress is empty! Ingress PODs are running fine.

I could create an alb manually which is what I did but it defeats the purpose. Any idea why alb didn't get created?

Thanks,
Prodip

Comment: Posted the question with more debugging logs at https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-alb-ingress-controller/issues/1202. Will share the final outcome once I come to know. In the meantime, follow this link for latest information on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is resolved. Posted the question to github and, guess what, developer knew the problem! See answer at the link below- https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-alb-ingress-controller/issues/1202

ALB ran into errors because I quoted the values in the args section of alb-ingress-controller. Args value should not be in quotes. Previously, those values were quoted and I got errors in the ingress controller logs.

Once I deleted the alb-ingress-controller and recreated, ALB was provisioned along with listener, rules, targets, security group, etc. based on the ingress resource definition. Now I can see the address and port fields are populated at the ingress.:)-

Error logs from ingress controller POD: 
E0324 01:43:45.026893 1 controller.go:217] kubebuilder/controller "msg"="Reconciler error" "error"="failed to build LoadBalancer configuration due to unable to fetch subnets. Error: WebIdentityErr: fa iled to retrieve credentials\ncaused by: RequestError: send request failed\ncaused by: Post https://sts.'us-east-1'.amazonaws.com/: dial tcp: lookup sts.'us-east-1'.amazonaws.com: no such host" "controller "="alb-ingress-controller" "request"={"Namespace":"default","Name":"aspnetapp-ingress"}

Ingress Controller deployment definition:

[image]

Comment: please don't use screenshots, paste and format your code